# Angular 6 animations on :increment and :decrement not triggering correctly

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

trying to wrap my head around animating a list of items where users can move items up and down, one at a time, one step at at a time.

I got all excited when the [documentation](https://v6.angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#increment-and-decrement-in-transitions) started talking about `:increment` and `:decrement` selector values. However, I can't seem to get this to work.

The StackBlitz is up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6ejbe

The gist of my code is:

```
animations: [
  trigger('move', [
    transition(':decrement', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('5s ease', style({ opacity: 1 }))]),
    transition(':increment', [style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)' }), animate('5s ease', style({ transform: 'scale(1)' }))]),
  ])
],
```

my html:

```
<div [@move]="index" *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
  <span (click)="moveUp(item)">^</span>&nbsp;<span (click)="moveDown(item)">v</span> {{index}} : {{item}} 
</div>
```

The result is pretty odd:

[image: crazy list]

First, it looks like only the `:increment` transition is kicking in (scale), not the `:decrement` (opacity).
Second, it seems that the transition only fires *once* per index.

Is this a bug with the transition/animations library?

Or am I just using/understanding it wrong?

**Update**

Part of the issue seems to be with the `*ngFor`. If I add a child `div` element and animate it, things are better, but not 100%.

Two issues still happening:

1. First, it seems that the `:increment` is working as expected, but the `:decrement` takes a couple of *rounds* to work.
2. Second, it seems that I have to use an inner `div` element. I can't seem to put the animation on an `ng-container`. This is a bit annoying as I don't like adding additional `div` elements just to *hack* something.

[image]

Comment: So, found out something interesting, it seems that the transition trigger on the `*ngFor` element is the culprit. If I simply move everything down one level and apply the transition to a child `div` element, it works... stay tuned!

Comment: Congrats! It seems that you already fixed the issue. Is there any other issues you are facing?

Comment: hi @GerardSans thanks for following-up (and thanks for your great article). I am still having the 2 issues I posted in the update where it doesn't seem to work the first couple of times I click on a particular item. This might be a bug and I will get around posted it on angular.
The second issue (need to create a child `div` element) might just be a misunderstanding on my part on how to use animations. I kinda had to focus on the actual business logic instead of animations the past couple of days...